# Apache Hive query on Tez FileNotFoundException

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

I'm receiving this exception when executing a Hive query on Tez with `Hive 2.3.6` and `Tez 0.9.2`

I know `Tez` is configured correctly because I can manually run map-reduce jobs via Hadoop.

```
Dag submit failed due to java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path is not a file: /tmp/hive/root/_tez_session_dir/f4f4b17c-0657-41fa-8674-df83fa3ad362/lib
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirStatAndListingOp.getBlockLocations(FSDirStatAndListingOp.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1829)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:381)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:503)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:871)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:817)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2606)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is seen on Hive 2.2+ or Hive 2.3.x+ when

`hive.aux.jars.path` in `hive-site.xml` is configured with an invalid path.

or

`HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH` environment variable is configured improperly (usually in `hive-env.sh`)